# How do I remove certain characters from multiple words in my file?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm making a random CK2 *(Crusader Kings II)* character generator and after a few days of struggle I managed (with some help) to parse the culture file in CK2's game directory into a JSON file where everything is now organized.

But many of the words are like this `"Helena_Helen"` or `"Inga_Inge"` So my question is this, how do I remove the underscore character and the text after that character with the Notepad++ regex and there are some random numbers and character at random places in the names.

Is there a way for me to remove those as well (Example: Ad\u00e0mu_Adam or Ad\u00e9mar_Ad\u00e9mar)?

Here's an shortened example of the code:

```
 "norse": {"male_names": ["Ale", "Alfr_Alf", "Alfgeir", "Anders_Andrew", "Anlaufr", "Anundr_Anund", "Arnbj\u00f6rn", "Arngrimr", "Arni_Arne", "Arnfast", "Asbj\u00f6rn_Asbj\u00f6rn", "Bagge", "Baldr_Balder", "Barid", "Bengt_Benedict", "Bersi", "Bertil_Berthold", "Birger", "Bj\u00f6rn_Beorn", "Bo", "Borkvard", "Botulfr_Botulf", "Bragi_Brage", "Bu\u00f0li", "Dag", "Dan", "Dyre", "Eilif", "Egill_Egil", "Emund", "Einarr_Einar", "Eirikr_Erik", "Eskild", "Falki", "Faste", "Filip_Philip", "Fredrik_Frederick", "Frirek", "Fro\u00f0i_Frode", "Freyr_Frej", "Folki_Folke", "Gandalfr", "Geirr", "Georg_George", "Gnupa_Gnupa", "Gorm_Gorm", "Greger_Gregory", "Grimr_Grim", "Gu\u00f0fri\u00f0_Godfrey", "Gu\u00f0mundr_Gudmund", "Gu\u00f0r\u00f6\u00f0r_Gudr\u00f6d", "Gunnarr_Gunnar", "Hakon_Hakon", "Halsten", "Haraldr_Harold", "Haukr", "Helgi_Helge", "Hemming", "Holmger", "Hrafn", "Hrolfr_Rolf", "Hrane", "H\u00e6steinn", "Hjalmar_Hjalmar", "Hro\u00f0gar", "Hro\u00f0ulfr", "Hr\u00f6rekr_Rurik", "Hysing", "Ing\u00f3lfr_Ingolf", "Ingemar", "Ingjald", "Ivar_Ivar", "Jedvard_Edward", "Jon_John", "Sigur\u00f0r_Sigurd", "Starka\u00f0r_Starkad", "Steinn_Sten", "Sturla", "Styrbj\u00f6rn", "Styrkar", "Sumarli\u00f0i_Somerled", "Suni_Sune", "Sveinn_Sven", "Sverker", "S\u00e6mundr_S\u00e4mund", "\u00deordis_Thordis", "\u00deyra_Thyra"]},
```

and some more at: https://pastebin.com/c3twKepK

Comment: Please add some information about the expected result for e.g. `Asbj\u00f6rn_Asbj\u00f6rn`?

Comment: Ok, so for some reason some of the names in the game's culture file are written like that etc.`Asbj\u00f6rn_Asbj\u00f6rn`. I'm not quite sure why that is, but whatever the case, I want to remove it if possible with Notepad++'s regex thing and those that are like this `Ivar_Ivar` I want to remove the underscore and the text after the underscore.

Comment: I managed to get the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the help regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pure text parts without UTF-8 special characters including the underline can be deleted with the following expression:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?=\_)(.*?)(?=\")`
- Replace with: `nothing`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Please note this also matches `_names` in `{"male_names": [`. As a workaround replace the underscore with a hash symbol and reset later.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this did the job!